# How do RGB numbers work?

Tags: css, rgb

I have a grey color of 222,222,222

What is the rule so I don't do try and error, For example if I know I want to make the grey a bit darker, how should I know which number should I change and should I go higher or lower?

Comment: RGB goes for Red, Green, Blue. So, if the numbers go up, you're increasing colors (from 0 to 255). If you reach 255,255,255, you will get white. If you remove all colors and go to 0,0,0, you will get black. If you get 0,255,0 you get 100% green, and so on. So, if you want to go darker, you should increase all 3 colors. Cheers.

Comment: If you think about what R, G and B stand for, then think for another minute about what they do in combination, you'd have your answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#Numeric_representations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the StackOverflow Documentation:
[image]